# Erro de permissões no WordPress - NextGEN Gallery

Tags: wordpress, permissões

Olá!

Estou usando o plugin NextGEN no WordPress e agora ele está apresentando o seguinte erro quando vou criar uma galeria:

> Could not write to file. Please check filesystem permissions. Filename: E:\home\construtor246\construtoraks.com.br\web\wp-content\gallery\teste

Alguém sabe como posso alterar essas permissões ou talvez o caminho dessas galerias dentro do plugin?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você está usando um servidor local ou em produção? Você pode alterar a permissão da pasta para 777 se for o caso.

Comment: Não é local, eu já estou usando o servidor do cliente. No server local deu tudo certo e num outro server meu que uso para testes também funcionou. Só aí que está dando problema... Como faço para alterar essa permissão? O que significa 777?

Comment: Expliquei na resposta. Veja se dá certo

Answer (score 1):

Com um servidor `FTP`, pode ser o (Filezilla) você vai até essa pasta wp-content  e clica com o botão direito sobre a pasta Gallery e vá `alterar permissões`, lá você seleciona os campos de gravar, editar, ler até que fique com permissão `777`, que é total. Assim você permite acesso a está pasta.

Comment: Pois é, fui dar uma fuçada aqui e achei isso. Mas já estava 777... E agora? Vou tentar fazer um teste deixando tudo 777 para ver!

Comment: Não rolou... Ele dá permissão negada... =/

Comment: Faça um teste na dando 755 nesta pasta, ou caso ainda não resolva, 777 na pasta /wp-content, (o ideal para essa pasta é 755 também), mas para testar, se ainda assim não der, ai vc aplica 755 na pasta wp-content e todas as subpastas